# How to Display error message in a alert instead of span class in AspNet MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using fluent validation and in my view there is a `<span asp-validation-for>` that appears under the input box when the field is wrong

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLIFn.png)

I want to change it to a javascript Alert

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I ask how you had FluentValidation setup? I work with Asp.net core so I setup mine through another middleware... If by any chance you manually create new instances of the validator upon every action then you could iterate through all the validation errors, concatenate all of them into one string then display it through javascript alert.

Like so:

```cs
public ActionResult Index(DataInput model)  
{ 
    string errorMessage = "";
    CustomValidator validator = new CustomValidator();  
    ValidationResult result = validator.Validate(model);  
    if (result.IsValid)  
    {  
        //... do successfull stuff here
        return View("SuccessfullView");
    }  
    else  
    {  
        foreach (ValidationFailure failer in result.Errors)  
        {  
            ModelState.AddModelError(failer.PropertyName, failer.ErrorMessage); 
            errorMessage += failer.PropertyName + " : " + failer.ErrorMessage + "\n"; 
        }  
    }
    ViewBag.Errors = errorMessage;  
    return View(model);  
}
```

And in your view you would do this :

```html
<body>
  @if(ViewBag.Errors != null){
    <script>alert('@ViewBag.Errors')</script>
  }
</body>
```